# NSFetchedResultsController and Relationship

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

This time I get a strange behavior with NSFetchedResultsController. I create a fetchRequest like this:

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entdesc = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Exam" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entdesc];
NSPredicate *predi = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"student == %@", self.student];
[fetchRequest setPredicate:predi];
```

If I execute it with `executeFetchRequest:error:` of NSManagedObjectContext, I get the expected Result. All Exams according to the student. (Between Student and exam is a one-to-many relationship)
But If I use the same fetchRequest in a NSFetchedResultsController, I get something different. Until now I didn't get out, what I exactly get. In my eyes the result is random.

Can you help me? I want to manage the exams of a given student with a NSFetchedResultsController.

Sandro Meier

Comment: `[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"student == %@", self.exam]`. Here, is `self.exam` a student?

Comment: Sorry my fault. Sure it has to be a student. ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a `Student` object already in hand, you don't have to fetch the `Exam` objects you just ask the `Student` object for the contents of its `exams` relationship. There is no need to fetch because you already have a reference to all the `Exam` objects you want.

As to why the fetch works outside the fetch results controller, I can't say with certainty. The controller does nothing but take the results of a fetch and package them for display in a tableview. If the data does not display properly in the tableview, then the problem is most likely in the tableview delegate/datasource methods where you connect the contents of the fetched results controller to tableview.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I thought also about this. But the NSFetchedResultsController does all the handling for me. If I don't find an other solution I'll do it in that way. ;-)

Comment: Yes same problem here. It is very convenient having the fetchcontroller to create all sections for your table.
What is the best practice here?